# Access Denied Error in IE8 using shopify

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, access-denied, shopify

I'm getting an "Access Denied" Error in IE8 when loading jquery 1.4.2 from google code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In Firefox, Chrome etc. everything works fine. I tried to load it from a local file on the server but since I'm using shopify it only works with their cdn and with this its the same access denied error.
this is the url:

http.://meinwein-online.de

I have no clue what to do. Can anyone help?

Cheers
Nick

Comment: Are you sure the "access denied" error comes up because of that `<script>`? How can you tell? I'm not getting the error from where I am by the way... Just errors complaining about jQuery not being loaded.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe its not the <script>-tag. But why ist jQuery not being loaded? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Well, you seem to have server-side issues that you probably need to sort out first: `Liquid error: Could not find asset snippets/jquery-latest.liquid` (that's what I see in the top left corner in Chrome. I don't know what liquid is so I don't know how to fix it)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm working on the problem right now and havent updated the file. This liquid code is old. Now I have updated the file.

Comment: the "access denied" is caused by something that is calling jQuery, either in your scripts or shopify's. You may need to install the Windows debugger to find out where it happens. As a hazy guess, it could be caused by a cross-domain Ajax request somewhere

Comment: Thank you. It was caused by a crossdomain ajax request which caused IE to throw an error.

Comment: Ah, cool. I'll add that as an answer then so you can close the question.

Answer (score 1):

the "access denied" is caused by something that is calling jQuery, either in your scripts or shopify's. You may need to install the Windows debugger to find out where it happens.

As a hazy guess, it could be caused by a cross-domain Ajax request somewhere.